# Gstreamer color convert on qmlglsink uses a lot of cpu

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I have videowall application written using qt + gstreamer, my pipeline looks like this:

rtspsrc ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glsinkbin sink=qmlglsink (for rtsp)

souphttpsrc ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glsinkbin sink=qmlglsink (for http)

I forced decodebin to use d3d11h264/265dec in the hope that all the load will be on the GPU, but d3d11h264dec gives an NV12 format image, and qmlglsink accepts only RGBA, so glsinkbin internally creates glcolorconvert and converts each frame to RGBA and I noticed a very high CPU load, in the case of rtsp it is 5-6% for each stream, and in the case of http streams, this is 7-9%, also when playing with d3d11videosink, there is no CPU load, so I decided that it was all about color conversion, maybe there are some ways to convert color to GPU or reduce CPU load?